# comparing lists with tuples in python

Tags: python, list, tuples

I have a list containing two words

```
list =  ["the","end"]
```

I have a list of tuples such as this

```
bigramslist = [ ("the", "end"), ("end", "of"), ("of", "the"), ("the", "world") ]
```

Is it possible to systematically go through each tuple in the bigramslist and see if both words in the list match any of the tuples in the bigramlist. And if so return true?

thanks

Comment: Are you looking for duplicates ?

Comment: Does (end, of) match (of, end), or do the tuples have to be in the same order to match?

Comment: yes the tuples have to be in the same order to match

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
>>> L1 = ["the","end"]
>>> bigramslist = [ ("the","end"), ("end","of"), ("of","the"), ("the","world") ]
>>> tuple(L1) in bigramslist
True
```

edit for completeness:

```
>>> bigramsset = set( [ ("the","end"), ("end","of"), ("of","the"), ("the","world") ] )
>>> L1 = ["the","end"]
>>> tuple(L1) in bigramsset
True
```

as jsbueno pointed out, using a set will result in a O(1) search time complexity where as searching the list is O(n). As a side note creating the set is also an additional O(n).

Comment: If the order in bigramslist does not matter, it should be a `set` instead of a list - that will speed-up the comparisons a lot. Just do `bigramslist = set(bigramslist)`  before checking for containement with the `in` operator.

Comment: @jsbueno: Indeed, although often you can construct a set in the first place instead of building a list, then building a set from that.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're after:

```
>>> list = ["the", "end"]
>>> bigramslist = [ ("the", "end"), ("end", "of"), ("of", "the"), ("the", "world") ]
>>> def check(list, biglist):
...     return [(list[0], list[1]) == big for big in biglist]
... 
>>> check(list, bigramslist)
[True, False, False, False]
>>>
```

Matches any of the compared values - you can then decide what to do if that list contains true.

Edit: Ok, kriegar's method is a lot better.